Are there any passages in the OT where the grammar is simplified to help children learn to read and write? (and speak!)
This is about both the Ancient Hebrew and the Septuagint, across the widest area and the longest timespan.
I'm terribly underpowered in anything to do with history, but I know that archaeology sometimes finds children's practice-exercises.
These ones are much later, but they show the sort of thing I mean:-
https://www.lib.cam.ac.uk/genizah-fragments/posts/how-did-jewish-children-learn-write-thousand-years-ago
======
The passages children enjoyed probably were the same then as now: the creation, the fall, Noah's ark, David & Goliath. But in the public domain is there statistical analysis of constructions, vocabulary, and 'complexity' passage by passage?
Alternatively, the repeated daily prayers that infants grow up with: those might have a social-phonetic role of reinforcing syntax and vowel-sounds (and therefore group identity). Like the KJV's Lord's Prayer becomes for English: 8 different vowels on the first line and a significant range of them covered by the end.

If you are seeking simple Hebrew, avoid the poetic passages.  A good start is actually, Genesis 1 which not poetic but repetitive and straight forward 9for the most part).

not specifically for children so much but --- Psalm 119 (by far the longest of the psalms)  is constructed with each stanza featuring  a sequential letter of the Hebrew alphabet. In English this would be something like "A is for angel..always praising God, above the earth, adversaries tremble, Adam's sons rejoice;  B is for blessing, be praised o Lord above, behemoth is his plaything, bow down O sons of men. (a weak imitation but hopefully this gives the idea. )

The Old Testament was never written for children. Although there are bits in it that children might come to remember once they could read ancient Hebrew (or the Greek of the Septuagint), they were to be taught about the Hebrew scriptures by their parents verbally inculcating it to them. They would be taught to read and write when old enough, but the Hebrew scriptures themselves were not (and still are not) written for children (if I've understood your question aright).
